# How to set fire on a web input fild?

Tags: angularjs, excel, vba, web-scraping, automation

I'm trying to set fire on a web input field, I tryed using fireevent. But seems this webpage doesn´t recognized my value, here is my last attempt:

```
Sub Import()

    Dim IE As InternetExplorer 
    Set IE = New InternetExplorer 
    IE.Visible = True 
    IE.Navigate "http://loterias.caixa.gov.br/wps/portal/loterias/landing/lotofacil"


    Do While IE.Busy = True
       Application.StatusBar = "Acessando Portal ..."
       DoEvents           
   Loop

    Do While IE.Busy = True
        DoEvents
    Loop

    While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Wend

    sng = Timer

    Do While sng + 1 > Timer
    Loop

    IE.Document.getElementById("buscaConcurso").Focus
    IE.Document.all("buscaConcurso").Value = "1692"

    Call TimerMore

    Call IE.Document.parentWindow.execScript("javascript: arregaResultadoForm($event)", "JavaScript")

End Sub

Sub TimerMore()

    newHour = Hour(Now())
    newMinute = Minute(Now())
    newSecond = Second(Now()) + 3
    waitTime = TimeSerial(newHour, newMinute, newSecond)
    Application.Wait waitTime

End Sub
```

[image: Textbox]

```
$scope.carregaResultadoForm = function (keyEvent){
        if(keyEvent.which===13){
            $scope.carregaResultado($scope.concursoSearch);
            startLoader();
        }
    }
```

Comment: "set fire" ?  Do you mean "set file" ?

Comment: @TimWilliams I think OP means "Fire an event" but... I've wanted to set fire to some VBA that I've come across so I'm hoping for a more literal interpretation.

Comment: I need the field "buscaConcurso" accept the new values and fire the events.

Comment: Should it be `carregaResultadoForm($event)`?

Comment: @Santosh That is the correct one as far as I saw.

Comment: @Santosh While debugging the code, I could see that the web page gets loaded successfully but the code gives error 80020101.

Comment: @Pedro What are you trying to get from the site?

Comment: @Santosh I trying to get the results on the left side: 03, 05, 07, 10, 12, 14, 15...

Comment: @Pedro Tried but no luck. The textbox is tied with angular js `ng-keypress` but unable to trigger the event.  fyi - I have added angular js tag.

Answer (score 0):

### Selenium:

Can improve on this but using [selenium basic](https://florentbr.github.io/SeleniumBasic/). After installing add reference to selenium type library and HTML Object Library.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim d As WebDriver, keys As New Selenium.keys, html As New HTMLDocument
    Set d = New ChromeDriver
    Const Url = "http://loterias.caixa.gov.br/wps/portal/loterias/landing/lotofacil"
    With d
        .AddArgument "--headless"
        .Start "Chrome"
        .get Url
        .FindElementById("buscaConcurso").SendKeys 1692
        .FindElementById("buscaConcurso").SendKeys keys.Enter
        Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2)
        html.body.innerHTML = .PageSource
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        WriteTable html.querySelector(".simple-table.lotofacil"), 1, ActiveSheet
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
       .Quit
   End With
End Sub

Public Sub WriteTable(ByVal hTable As HTMLTable, Optional ByVal startRow As Long = 1, Optional ByVal ws As Worksheet)

    If ws Is Nothing Then Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Dim tSection As Object, tRow As Object, tCell As Object, tr As Object, td As Object, R As Long, c As Long, tBody As Object
    R = startRow
    With ws
        Dim headers As Object, header As Object, columnCounter As Long
        Set headers = hTable.getElementsByTagName("th")
        For Each header In headers
            columnCounter = columnCounter + 1
            .Cells(startRow, columnCounter) = header.innerText
        Next header
        startRow = startRow + 1
        Set tBody = hTable.getElementsByTagName("tbody")
        For Each tSection In tBody               'HTMLTableSection
            Set tRow = tSection.getElementsByTagName("tr") 'HTMLTableRow
            For Each tr In tRow
                R = R + 1
                Set tCell = tr.getElementsByTagName("td")
                c = 1
                For Each td In tCell             'DispHTMLElementCollection
                    .Cells(R, c).Value = td.innerText 'HTMLTableCell
                    c = c + 1
                Next td
            Next tr
        Next tSection
    End With
End Sub
```

---

### XHR:

You can also use the [API](https://confiraloterias.com.br/api/lotofacil/) to get a JSON response and parse the info you want:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim strURL As String, strJSON As String, Http As Object, concurso As Long
    concurso = 1692
    strURL = "http://confiraloterias.com.br/api0/json.php?loteria=lotofacil&concurso=" & concurso & "&token=dO7rI7JcyfnSlFn"

    Set Http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    With Http
        .Open "GET", strURL, False
        .send
        strJSON = .responseText
    End With

    Debug.Print Split(Split(strJSON, "[")(1), "]")(0)
End Sub
```

---

**Example section of JSON response:**

[image: response]

Comment: selenium webdriver is not working and also sendkeys is hard to make work reliably.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? And as this is browser automation sendkeys is a common method. Nothing in the above shifts window focus either.

Comment: I tested the above multiple times without fail.

Comment: Not yet, I'm still looking for a soluticion with IE

Comment: So how can I do that ?

Comment: You just run the code at the very bottom (under XHR) as is. Put the code in a standard module and execute it.

Comment: I have set it to print to the immediate window which you open with Ctrl + G in the VBE.

Comment: Can this be considered answered please?